# How can I constrain loadings to be greater or equal to 0 in lavaan?

Tags: r, r-lavaan

I am currently running a bifactor model with 1 general factor and 3 group factors. Some loadings on the third factor end up negative, even though they are positive and strong when running a 3 factor hierachical model. I've read that a remedy for this is to constrain them to be in the positive direction. How can I do that? I would greatly appreciate some input.

My code:

```
  Bifactor<-'
  s =~ S1+S2+S3+S4+S5+S6
  p  =~ P1+P2+P3+P4+P5+P6
  c =~ C1+C2+C3+C4+C5+C6
  
  g  =~ S1+S2+S3+S4+S5+S6+P1+P2+P3+P4+P5+P6+C1+C2+C3+C4+C5+C6
 '
 Bifactor.fit<-cfa(Bifactor,data=pras,estimator="MLM", orthogonal=TRUE, std.lv=TRUE)

 summary(Bifactor.fit,fit.measures=TRUE,standardized=TRUE)
```

Comment: bifactor loadings don't have the same interpretation as indirect effects of g on indicators in a higher-order factor model.  But you can label any parameter (e.g., `c =~ foo*C1`) and specify inequality constraints in the syntax (e.g., `foo >= 0`).

Comment: @Terrence Thank you doctor! In light of this issue, would you reccomend to me to apply this constrain? I am not sure whether by doing it I remedy a lavaan problem or I bias my model. 

An exploratory bifactor analysis (rank defficient SL) yielded adequate, positive loadings for this group factor. In light of this I get extra confused as to why a CFA model ends with very different results.